# ChemDraw temporary label for chemnum LaTeX

Tags: software

Currently I'm searching for a nice way to implement my ChemDraw graphics into $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$.

There is a package called `chemnum` which will auto-label the compounds in the `eps`-graphic which sounds nice. The package describes, that I need to put "temporary markers" inside the document where the number should be.

How do I get these markers? I guess it is not a normal text area, isn't it? I'm using ChemDraw 16.0.1.4.

Comment: It's better to ask $\mathrm{\LaTeX}$-related questions on [TeX.SE](https://tex.stackexchange.com/). There is already a [plethora of similar questions there](https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bchemnum%5D+chemdraw), check them out – probably you'll find an answer.

Comment: This is not about LateX. It is about chemdraw. Thats why the question is in here but I will check out the Questions in the Tex.Stackexchange

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's software issue.

Comment: Just put `tmp1` etc below the compounds you want to label, then let the latex macro replace those with the actual numbers from the aux-files. This requires at least two runs, and you are limited to using epslatex. There are certain drawbacks to this.

Answer (score 1):

The [ChemNum package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/chemnum/chemnum_en.pdf) that can be found on [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/chemnum) specifies:

> Create the scheme and place temporary tags like TMP1, TMP2 and so on where you want the compound labels to be.

A question on [TeX.SX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/371450/16347) specifies:

> When you create a text box and type into it, it will store it as a string correctly in the EPS. However, it was (sometimes) automatically putting it into chemical formula mode - so that in TMP1, the 1 was subscript (TMP<sub>1</sub>). Even if you fix this manually, it now saves the `TMP` and `1` separately in the EPS, meaning CHemNum fails to find `TMP1`.

Thus, it seems all you need to do is create textboxes with the appropriate labels.

Comment: And for creating textboxes with the appropriate labels in ChemDraw see also this question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/45055/7951